# i18n is not working in sapui5. (wp8)

Tags: internationalization, windows-phone-8.1, sapui5

My i18n is not working, I don't know what is wrong, below my manifest.json:

```
   {
"_version": "1.1.0",
"sap.app": {
    "_version": "1.1.0",
    "id": "de.pensware.ui5StocksApp",
    "type": "application",
    "i18n": "i18n/i18n.properties"

},

"sap.ui": {
    "technology": "UI5",
    "icons": {
        "icon": "",
        "favIcon": "",
        "phone": "",
        "phone@2": "",
        "tablet": "",
        "tablet@2": ""
    },
    "deviceTypes": {
        "desktop": true,
        "tablet": true,
        "phone": true
    },
    "supportedThemes": [
        "sap_bluecrystal"
    ]
},

"sap.ui5": {
    "_version": "1.1.0",
    "rootView": {
        "viewName": "de.pensware.ui5StocksApp.view.App",
        "type": "XML"
    },

    "dependencies": {
        "minUI5Version": "1.30.0",
        "libs": {
            "sap.ui.core": {},
            "sap.m": {},
            "sap.ui.layout": {}
        }
    },
    "contentDensities": {
        "compact": true,
        "cozy": true
    },
        "models": {
        "i18n": {
            "type": "sap.ui.model.resource.ResourceModel",
            "settings": {
                "bundleName": "de.pensware.ui5StocksApp.i18n.i18n"
            }
        }
    },
    "routing": {
        "config": {
            "routerClass": "sap.m.routing.Router",
            "viewType": "XML",
            "viewPath": "de.pensware.ui5StocksApp.view",
            "controlId": "app",
            "controlAggregation": "pages",
            "transition": "slide"
        },

        "routes": [{
            "name": "login",
            "pattern": "",
            "target": "login"
        }],
        "targets": {
            "login": {
                "viewName": "Login",
                "viewId": "Login"

            }
        }
    }
}
```

}

In my aplication  I have a folder called i18n and the i18n.properties file.

In My view I have :

```
   <Page title="{i18n>appTitle}">
```

But when I execute the app in a mobile windows phone it's not showing me the corresponding text traslation, it is showing  only "appTitle" value.

Comment: Is it just not working on WP8, or does it also not working on other platforms (e.g. your browser)?

Comment: I'm testing on WebIde and it works perfectly! tks

Comment: In that case you might want to post this as a platform incompatibility through  https://github.com/SAP/openui5/issues (in case you are using openui5) or through the service market place (if you are using sapui5).

Comment: Thank you, I'm going to post it at marketplace.